# Desinstalar Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu

tengo Ubuntu 19.10 instalado en la misma particion que windows 10, esta version de ubuntu permitia hacer esto sin tener que formatear C:/ que es la particion donde ya tenia windows.
La pregunta es ahora, hay alguna forma de desinstalar ubuntu (sin tener) que formatear el disco.

Saludos y Gracias

---

[image: Disco]
Esta la imagen del disco marcado en rojo donde tengo tanto windows como Ubuntu, en la respuesta anterior me explican que debo formatear el disco y es esto lo que quiero evitar

Comment: Pienso que la respuesta está aqui: https://youtu.be/ZTMCKOx5Jz0
En todo caso, por favor suba un pantallazo de su Disk Management para verificarlo.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no parece versar sobre dudas de programación, por favor leer [ask]

Comment: Stack Overflow es un sitio para profesionales y aficionados de la programación, personas que escriben código porque aman hacerlo. Creemos que las mejores preguntas en Stack Overflow tienen siempre un poco de código pero si tu pregunta es acerca de…

un problema específico de programación, o
un algoritmo de software, o
herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software
Entonces pienso que mi pregunta a un problema real esta en espacio abarcado por el grupo. Saludos

Comment: Lo comenté por que tu preguntaq esta enfocada a la instalación de un SO y no al desarrollo de software como tal entonces como tal me parece no se ajusta al formato del sitio

Comment: Ciertamente la pregunta es muy amplia. No sabemos qué has intentado, qué no, qué has investigado, etc. Desinstalar un SO no es trivial y hay muchos caminos que pueden recorrerse. Tal vez la pregunta sí pertenezca a StackOverflow, pero no de la manera que está escrita. Cuando buscas "desinstalar ubuntu" en Google hay muchos resultados útiles.